# How do I write this PHP string that has an equal sign within it?

Tags: php, html, string, url

```
<?
$xm="1?x=1";
if($_GET["x"]=="1" || $_GET["x"]=='$xm'){ ?>
String Works
<? } ?>
```

Basically the URL reads:

```
http://site.com/shop/category/product?x=1?x=1
```

This happens when a form is submitted. I do not have access to change it to:

```
http://site.com/shop/category/product?x=1&x2=1
```

Comment: Use Preg_Replace - a string cannot have an equal sign within it. Text or Numeric. BONKERS.

Comment: Use `http_build_query()` instead.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Comment: To change the URI you must to launch a redirection command. Take a look to http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Try `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to get the raw query string,which you can then manipulate. $_GET will only have the **LAST** `x` value found in the query string, unless the query was built with the `x[]` notation.

Comment: @m1th: `$x = "1+1=2";`? huh? why can a string not have an equal sign in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```
<?
$xm="1?x=1";
if($_GET["x"]=="1" || $_GET["x"]=="{$xm}"){ ?>
String Works
<? } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the URL looks like `...product?x=1?x=1`, the `$_GET` array will look like this:

```
array(1) {
    ["x"] => string(5) "1?x=1"
}
```

So your condition just needs to look like:

```
if ($_GET["x"] == '1?x=1')
```

Your problem is simply that you quote the variable `$xm` in single quotes, which literally results in the string "$xm".

Now obviously, that's a rather broken URL. If you don't know how many times `?x=1` will occur in it, it's hard to compare to anything constant.

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work, with the change that `'$xm'` will not evaluate to `"1?x=1"`:

```
if (isset($_GET['x']) && ($_GET['x'] == 1 || $_GET['x'] == $xm)) {
    echo 'string works';
}
```

If the argument will always be numeric, you can also just write this to coerce `$_GET['x']` into an integer before comparison:

```
if (isset($_GET['x']) && $_GET['x'] == 1) {
    echo 'string works';
}
```

This works because `'1?x=1' == 1`, but also `'1?x=2' == 1` ... if that's not the desired behavior, do let me know.

Answer (score -2):

use [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) whenever you want to build links

Comment: OP wants to pull apart that url so it can be rebuilt. you're talking about how to paint a wall, while OP is asking how to built the wall in the first place.

Answer (score -2):

equal sign has special meaning in url context. they need to be encoded to treat them like literal value either with urnencode() or rawurlencode() or base64 encode

Comment: That is not what the question is about.